# Hibernate : Splitting table automatically every month

Tags: java, database, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am working on a Spring-MVC application with PostgreSQL and Hibernate in which I have a few tables for which the row count is going in excess of 1 lakh(100 thousand). These tables, I am 95% of the time accessing only the latest data, and sifting through all these rows is time consuming. Many times the query planner is not even using indexes (for reasons unknown to me).

Then I thought of splitting database tables every week, so we can just access first the latest months database and then if the user requests, then more results from previous table will be directly added to the request.

Most of the queries performed require a JOIN for us, as tables mapped with one-to-many.

One of the model files where row count is > than 100 thousand.

Model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groupnotehistory")
public class GroupNoteHistory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "mhistoryid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mhistory_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mhistory_gen", sequenceName = "mhistory_seq")
    private int mhistoryid;


    @Column(name = "mnoteeditdate",columnDefinition = "timestamp without time zone")
    private Timestamp mnoteEditDate;

    @Column(name = "oldheadline", columnDefinition = "character varying")
    @Type(type="jasyptHibernateEncryptor")
    private String oldHeadLine;

    @Column(name = "oldtext", columnDefinition = "character varying")
    @Type(type="jasyptHibernateEncryptor")
    private String oldText;

    @Column(name = "newnotetext", columnDefinition = "character varying")
    @Type(type="jasyptHibernateEncryptor")
    private String newNoteText;

    @Column(name = "newnoteheadline", columnDefinition = "character varying")
    @Type(type="jasyptHibernateEncryptor")
    private String newNoteHeadline;


@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mnoteid", nullable = false)
    private GroupNotes mhistory;
// Getters and setters

}
```

Does Hibernate provide any strategies or way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like this might be a good time to consider alternate data stores, such as an append-only log store.

Comment: @chrylis : How can I query them or retrieve specific data-set from it?

Answer (score 0):

What about having the data split across several tables like:

- current values (up to a week) - table latest_values
- also older values (up to a year) - table year_values
- all values (complete history) - table all_values

Insert always into the latest_values and have rules push them to the other ones as well.

On a daily or weekly basis you run a "DELETE FROM latest_values WHERE insert_date < CURRENT_DATE - 7". On a monthly basis you run "DELETE FROM year_values WHERE insert_date < CURRENT_DATE - 365" (leap years don't matter here).

This way you keep tables small and can retrieve more current values easily, and still have all values at hand should a query need them.

Splitting every week into a separate table (that's how I understand your idea) would leave you with too many tables and complicated - thus slow - UNION operations if you need data from many weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column like period. This will store the year-month row was added.
This will act as partitioning.
When you run query for recent data you can specify which period (YYYYMM) you are looking for . This will reduce overhead which you are facing right now.

If you actually want to have partitioned DB which is best solution for this problem check out this 
[PostgresSQL DOC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

Comment: How can I do this? Manually?